# no displaying raw html in v-html vue 3 tag

Tags: html, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to display a raw html in a v-html tag that get from a http request, when I launch the app there is nothing to be displayed inside this tag
here is my tag:

```
 <div :v-html="html.value"></div>
```

here my script:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { onMounted, reactive, ref } from 'vue'
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
import axios from 'axios'

const route = useRoute()
let html = ref()


async function pedirEmailDetail() {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get<any[]>(url)
    html.value = data[0].body1
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    throw error
  }
}

onMounted(async () => {
  await pedirEmailDetail()
})
</script>
```

finally I attach here the html I get from the backend to make sure that I'm getting a string with html format, don't know that if the style tag could influence in rendering the html, I need to make this attribute dynamically by a reactive varibale:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<title>Global STAR</title>
<style type="text/css">

body {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.journal-content-article p{
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 1.1
}
div {
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 1.1
}
.Estilo1 {
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 1.1
}
.Estilo2 {font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;  color: #000E78;line-height: 1.1}
.Estilo3 {
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #000E78;
 line-height: 1.1
}
.Estilo5 {
 font-size: 10px;
 color: #666666;
 line-height: 1.1
}
.Estilo6 {font-size: 12px;  color: #666666; line-height: 1.1}
a:link {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #5b59aa;
}
a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
}
a:visited {
 text-decoration: none;
}
a:active {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.Estilo10 {color: #333333}
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}
.tg td{padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color: #c5c5c5;}
.tg th{padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color: #c5c5c5;}
.derecha{text-align: right;}
</style>
</head>

<body>


 <img src="https://www.enlazo.com/img/email/logo_globalstar.png" width="120" height="83" border="0" style="background-color:#000e78;text-align:right;font-family: arial; color: #ffffff; font-style: italic; font-size: 20px;font-weight: bold" alt="Global. STAR." />

<p class="Estilo3">Factura electrónica Global STAR</p>

<p class="Estilo1">Estimado cliente:</p><p class="Estilo1">Le informamos que su <span style="color: #326496">factura electrónica Global STAR</span> <b>H.2023/00019172</b> de fecha <b>15/07/2023</b> y con importe total (impuestos incluidos) de  <b>84,42 &euro;</b> correspondiente al titular <b>YOURCOOPTRANS, COOP.V (JOAQUIN RIBAS MONTILLA)</b> ya está disponible.</p>



<p class="Estilo1">Para obtener su factura y correspondientes anexos, puede:</p>

<blockquote class="Estilo1">
  <p><span class="Estilo9">1.</span> Descargar directamente la factura pulsando en el siguiente enlace:
  </p>

<p>
<a href="http://www.enlazo.com/GrupoEuropaFrontend/descargaFacturaCliente?idHash=306C57722F4141414149416A744E3979316D556B75325955596A466263346D566A637A4B6A79597448397761646837477664&fra=2219199&reference=2219199" target="_blank">
  <img src="http://www.enlazo.com/img/email/descarga_facturas.png" height="86" width="300" style="background-color: #326496;text-align:center;font-family: arial; color: #ffffff;  font-size: 20px;font-weight: bold" alt="Descarga de Facturas">
</a>
</p>
<p><span class="Estilo9">2.</span> Entre al Área Privada de cliente de www.enlazo.com :</p>

<p>
<a href="https://www.enlazo.com/GrupoEuropa/login.jsp" target="_blank">
  <img src="http://www.enlazo.com/img/email/boton-area-privada.png" height="86" width="300" style="background-color: #326496;text-align:center;font-family: arial; color: #ffffff;  font-size: 20px;font-weight: bold" alt="Área Privada">
</a>
</p>
<p class="Estilo5">Para acceder a esta información deberá usar las claves de acceso que le hemos facilitado. Si no las tiene todavía o no las recuerda, puede solicitarlas <a href="https://www.enlazo.com/GrupoEuropa/registro.action"><b> aquí.</b></a></p>
</blockquote>

<p class="Estilo1">Como usuario de la
<span style="color: #326496">Factura electrónica Global STAR</span>
, sus facturas estarán disponibles desde la fecha de emisión en la web <a href="http://www.enlazo.com/GrupoEuropa/login.jsp" target="_blank"> www.enlazo.com</a>, donde puede consultarla y/o descargarla. Todas sus facturas estarán disponibles por un periodo mínimo de 5 años.</p>
<p class="Estilo1">Con la facturación electrónica está colaborando a cuidar el medioambiente, porque cada gesto, cada pequeño detalle, cuenta.</p>

<p class="Estilo2" style="display:block;">Global STAR</p>
  <ul class="Estilo10">
    <li class="Estilo1">902 356 000 / +34 968 356 000</li>
    <li class="Estilo1"><a href="http://www.enlazo.com">www.enlazo.com</a></li>
    <li class="Estilo1"><a href="mailto:globalstar@enlazo.com">globalstar@enlazo.com</a></li>
    <li class="Estilo1"><a href="https://twitter.com/GlobalSTAR_es">Twitter</a></li>
    <li class="Estilo1"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/GlobalSTAR.es">Facebook</a></li>
    <li class="Estilo1"><a href="https://wa.me/34629077235">Whatsapp</a></li>
  </ul>

<p class="Estilo6">PROTECCIÓN DE DATOS: Los datos personales que forman parte de este correo electrónico son tratados por GRUPO EUROPA ENLAZO con la finalidad de mantener informados a los contactos de los servicios y productos de la entidad. Los datos se han obtenido con su consentimiento o como consecuencia de una relación jurídica previa. Puede usted ejercitar sus derechos, así como obtener más información solicitándolo al correo electrónico: <a href="mailto:rgpd@enlazo.com">rgpd@enlazo.com</a>.</p>
<p class="Estilo6">En caso de no ser el destinatario de esta información, por favor, rogamos nos lo comunique en la dirección del remitente para la eliminación de su dirección electrónica, no copiando ni entregando este mensaje a nadie más y procediendo a su destrucción.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's a typo, the directive is called as `v-html`, not `:v-html` (note the `:`)

Comment: This is XHTML, not HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-html` is a directive so it's value is already a JS expression, no need in the `:` prefix. When you set the prefix, it becomes a property or an attribute!

```
<div :v-html="msg"></div>
```

is rendered to:

```
<div v-html="Hello World!"></div>
```